# Spring Cloud Streams not setting the kafka key in the message?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

The story is like this. I have a kafka broker and a particular object (which I jsonify to send through my topics) which has an ID I want to use as a key.

Currently I'm using the 'partitionKeyExtractorClass' configuration to set the class which extracts the ID and returns it as the key.

It looks like this:

```
def extractKey(Message<?> message) {
    log.info('Extracting key from message')
    String id = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(message.payload)).properties.id
    log.info("Got = ${id}")

    return id
}
```

My actual problem is that when I browse the message on the topic the ConsumerRecord which holds my message says that the key is null...

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Documentation on this doesn't go further than this.

Answer (score 2):

Look, you are mixing `partition` with `key`.

Currently the `KafkaMessageChannelBinder` doesn't provide option to determine the `key` against `Message`.

Only existing functionality which you can use powerfully is `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`:

```
    Object messageKey = this.messageKeyExpression != null
            ? this.messageKeyExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, message)
            : message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY);
```

So, before `output` message you should calculate the key and place it into that header.

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution. I have the same issue. I use the raw mode output. I don't want any headers in my messages, but the key needs to be set. I don't want to have to switch to apache camel.

Comment: Your concern isn't clear. That is a limitation of the current Kafka Binder implementation where mesageKey is just an omission. Feel free to fill out the issue, though. You can just configure Kafka Binder do not map that header for now if you care about that a lot. And I absolutely don't understand how Apache Camel can replace Spring Cloud Stream...

Comment: The issue is that I am integrating streams with other producers and consumers besides Spring Cloud Streams. The message key is important to guarantee order on the kafka topic. Having Spring Cloud Streams control headers means that all other producers and consumers must deal with Spring Cloud Streams specific headers. I need the kafka message to be exactly what I want it to be, not what Spring Cloud Streams wants it to be. A simple key and String message is what I need. raw mode gives me that, but no key to maintain order.

Comment: And Apache Camel has exactly the same capability; to read a stream of messages, process them in some way, and route/produce new messages from the processed data.